# JSX conditional rendering inline question <option disabled value="">Choose a value</option>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sabre

I know the inline is working because in the Convert HK to Passive Segment paragraph at the top I'm getting the expected result. What I want is for there to be a Choose a hotel when there's more than one hotel in the array but if there's only one hotel then don't add it and the person sees the dropdown with the only hotel displayed.

I'm a **newbie**. This is a typescript project working with React. The var howmany is evaluating.
Whether there's 1 hotel or 10 hotels this line
`{howmany > 1 && <option disabled value="">Choose a hotel </option>}`
will never render - why?
Originally I had this and it didn't work (in case the issue was key related...
`{howmany > 1 && <option key=0 value="">Choose a hotel </option>}`

```
render(): JSX.Element {
    const howmany: number = this.state.hotelList.length;

    return (
      <div className="tab-pane" id="hotelscript">
        <p>Convert HK to Passive Segment {howmany > 1 && `True`}</p>

        <form id="FormHkToYk" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="form">
          <div className="form-row">
            <label htmlFor="hotelList">Hotel List ({howmany})</label>
            <select
              className="form-control"
              name="hotelList"
              onChange={this.getThisHotel.bind(this)}
            >
              {howmany > 1 &&
                `<option disabled value="">Choose a hotel </option>`}
              {this.state.hotelList.map((h) => (
                <option key={h.Id} value={h.Id}>
                  {h.Id}- {h.HotelInformation.Name} -{" "}
                  {h.ReservationDetails.CheckIn}
                </option>
```

Comment: I am not entirely clear on what you trying to achieve. If there is one hotel then you want to show just "Choose a hotel" without any hotels. And when there more than one hotel you want to show a drop down with all hotels options? Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

So, to clarify your question;

> Whether there's 1 hotel or 10 hotels this line `{howmany > 1 && <option disabled value="">Choose a hotel </option>}` will never render - why?

Because, you will only render it when `howmany` or `this.state.hotelList.length` is **more than 1** - So, it will only render when it's **2 and above**

> What I want is for there to be a Choose a hotel when there's more than one hotel in the array but if there's only one hotel then don't add it and the person sees the dropdown with the only hotel displayed

Therefore, you can do the following;

```
<form id="FormHkToYk" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="form">
    <div className="form-row">
    <label htmlFor="hotelList">Hotel List ({howmany})</label>
    <select
        className="form-control"
        name="hotelList"
        onChange={this.getThisHotel.bind(this)}
    >
        {
            howmany === 1 ? (
                <option key={this.state.hotelList[0].Id} value={this.state.hotelList[0].Id}>
                    {this.state.hotelList[0].Id}- {this.state.hotelList[0].HotelInformation.Name} - {this.state.hotelList[0].ReservationDetails.CheckIn}
                </option>
            ) : (
                howmany > 1 && (
                    <option disabled value="">Choose a hotel </option>
                    {
                        this.state.hotelList.map((h) => (
                            <option key={h.Id} value={h.Id}>
                                {h.Id}- {h.HotelInformation.Name} - {h.ReservationDetails.CheckIn}
                            </option>
                        )
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    </select>
</form>
```

Notes regarding the code above:

1. The code above doesn't cover when **there's 0 hotels** case.
2. You should replace `this.state.hotelList[0]` to the variable of the first hotel, if any.

Answer (score 0):

So thank you Choz and Nikita for responding so quickly... It's one of those weird things I guess ...  I got this method working which is essentially what I was originally doing. I had experimented with choz's idea but for some reason unbalanced brackets or combining the choose a hotel option with the others caused an issue.

Maybe I was misunderstanding you choz.

Anyway this seems to work - I put the

```
<option value="">Select a hotel please.....</option>;
```

above the render making it a little cleaner to view within the render statement itself.
Not sure, what happened but I swear I tried that earlier.

So this is good...
If > 1 hotel then it says "select a hotel please..." otherwise it's just 1 hotel (yes, I validate that prior) so it will default to that hotel. Thank you all for the prompt responses... cheers... just sharing in case anyway wants to say my solution is bad.

```
render(): JSX.Element {
    const howmany: number = this.state.hotelList.length;
    let dropdownList;
    //   this isn't working....
    if (howmany > 1) {
      dropdownList = <option value="">Select a hotel please.....</option>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="tab-pane" id="hotelscript">
        <p>Convert HK to Passive Segment</p>

        <form id="FormHkToYk" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="form">
          <div className="form-row">
            <label htmlFor="hotelList">Hotel List ({howmany})</label>
            <select
              className="form-control"
              name="hotelList"
              onChange={this.getThisHotel.bind(this)}
            >
              {dropdownList}
              {this.state.hotelList.map((h) => (
                <option key={h.Id} value={h.Id}>
                  {h.Id}- {h.HotelInformation.Name} -{" "}
                  {h.ReservationDetails.CheckIn}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
```